# Joint probability given co-variances

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given 3 Bernoulli random variables $X,Y,Z \sim B(0.5)$, and their pairwise covariances: $Cov(X,Y) = a_1, Cov(X,Z) = a_2, Cov(Y,Z) = a_3$, I am interested in finding the expectation of their product, $\mathbb{E}[XYZ]$.

I suspect it may be impossible since I only have pairwise information, while this expectation requires more, e.g. $\mathbb{P}(X=1 | Y=1 \wedge Z=1)$. If so, can I say something about the connection between the product and the covariances? (for example: $\mathbb{E}$ is increasing in $a_1, a_2, a_3$). In addition, in what cases can we say something about a "global" property given only the covariances? If I had a vector $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ drawn from multivariate Gaussian distribution, can I say something about e.g. $\mathbb{P}[||X|| < C]$ (this also requires information about more than two events)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the Bernoulli case. It is not possible to find $P(X=1,Y=1,Z=1)$. However in the case of jointly Gaussian variables it is possible to deteremine the entire joint distribution  from just the covariances. This is special property of jointly Gaussian random variables.

Comment: Does $P(X = Y = Z = 1)$ necessarily increases in the covariances?